# Error when trying to create an event handler from a parent form

Tags: c++, windows, forms

I am trying to handle an event of some form from the form that creates it as follows

```
     Atom^ atomForm = gcnew Atom();
             atomForm->FormClosed+= gcnew System::Windows::Forms::FormClosedEventHandler(atomForm,&Form1::Atom_FormClosed);
             atomForm->ShowDialog();
```

but it is generating this error
Error   1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'LRTSimulation::Atom ^' to 'LRTSimulation::Form1 ^'   LRTDesign.h 167 1   LRTSimulation

I used to do this peacefully in C#. How can I avoid it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 gcnew FormClosedEventHandler(atomForm, &Form1::Atom_FormClosed);
```

You are passing the wrong object.  Clearly the Atom_FormClosed() method is a method of the Form1 class.  So you need to pass an object of type Form1.  Which can't be *atomForm*, as the error message told you.

It is probably *this*, although we can't see where this code is located.

You never had a problem with this in C# because that language doesn't permit specifying the delegate target object like C++/CLI does.